# Adjust frame title rule with tcolorbox

Tags: mdframed, tcolorbox

I have been unable to locate an example using `tcolorbox` which sets the color and width of the line below the frame title independent of the background color of the frame title.  With `mdframed` one can control these via `frametitlerulecolor=red` and `frametitlerulewidth=4pt`:

[image]

What are the equivalent options when using `tcolorbox`?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\mdfsetup{
    roundcorner=4pt,
    linewidth=1.5pt,
    frametitlerule=true, 
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=olive!15,
    % ----------------------------------
    frametitlerulecolor=red,%    How do I get the equivalent of two 
    frametitlerulewidth=4pt,%    options when using {tcolorbox}?
}

\tcbset{
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=olive!15,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=green!25, frametitle={Mdframed}]
    Content
\end{mdframed}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!25, title={Tcolorbox}]
    Content
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The line thicknes can be controlled by `titlerule=3mm`

Comment: @samcarter: That works great. Now just need something like `coltitlerule=` so that one can adjust the color as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To control the line thickness for the title rule, you can use the `titlerule=<length>` option; unfortunately, in the current version (3.36 when this answers was written) there's no key to individually control the color of the title rule and this line will inherit the frame color; I'm sure Thomas will add this option in a new update :) In the meantime, you can use `enhanced` and an `overlay` to control the attributes individually; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\mdfsetup{
    roundcorner=4pt,
    linewidth=1.5pt,
    frametitlerule=true, 
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=olive!15,
    % ----------------------------------
    frametitlerulecolor=red,%    How do I get the equivalent of two 
    frametitlerulewidth=4pt,%    options when using {tcolorbox}?
}

\tcbset{
    enhanced,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=olive!15,
    titlerule=0mm,
    overlay={
      \path[draw,red,line width=4pt] ([yshift=-2pt]title.south west) -- ([yshift=-2pt]title.south east);
    } 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=green!25, frametitle={Mdframed}]
    Content
\end{mdframed}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!25, title={Tcolorbox}]
    Content
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I take Gonzalo's suggestion as feature request :-)

With `tcolorbox` version `3.40 (2015/01/14)`, there is a new key `titlerule style` to set the color (or other style options) for the title rule:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\mdfsetup{
    roundcorner=4pt,
    linewidth=1.5pt,
    frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=olive!15,
    % ----------------------------------
    frametitlerulecolor=red,%    How do I get the equivalent of two
    frametitlerulewidth=4pt,%    options when using {tcolorbox}?
}

\tcbset{
    enhanced,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=olive!15,
    % ----------------------------------
    toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,%  fill in some more 'air' into the title
    titlerule style=red,
    titlerule=4pt,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=green!25, frametitle={Mdframed}]
    Content
\end{mdframed}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!25, title={Tcolorbox}]
    Content
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Further examples from the documentation:

[image]